# Delphi 7 Error. Project not opening in RAD Studio XE5

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl, delphi-xe5

I have a project in Borland Delphi 7. When I open the .DPR project file in RAD STUDIO XE5 it prompts an error "Framework not registered: VCL" and project not open.

I want to know what this error means. Although project is compiling and running in Borland Delphi 7.If you Google this error then there is not a single page for this error. Please help me. Thanks.

ERROR SCREENSHOT:

[image]
http://s9.postimg.org/9p6hyqodb/error.png

Comment: If you are using architect trial you should contact vendor for support

Comment: Of course it is hard to help without seeing a small repro.

Comment: Yes I am using trial version of RAD STUDIO XE5

Comment: So contact the vendor

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of FireMonkey, a project needs to know whether it is using VCL or FMX as its underlying framework.  When you upgrade your D7 project to XE5, the migration is not inserting that reference into the new DPROJ.

Unfortunately, upgrading older projects to newer IDEs has always been a flawed process full of pproblems. The best option is to simply do not do it.  Create a new project from scratch and add your existing source files to it as needed.

Comment: The error message reads quite differently. It suggests that the IDE knows it is vcl and claims not to recognise it.